# list has 8 items but the the last 4 items moves out from the blue background in testimonials-section

Tags: javascript, html, css

As i am running the `html` and `css` code the list of testimonials are 8 but , when i increased the size of the screen to 950px the list of 8 items start coming out of the background, so please can anyone give me the hint that where the code is wrong

```js
const mobileBtn = document.getElementById('mobile-cta');
nav = document.querySelector('nav');
mobileBtnExit = document.getElementById('mobile-sta');

mobileBtn.addEventListener('click' , () => {
 nav.classList.add('mobile-menu');
})
mobileBtnExit.addEventListener('click' , () => {
nav.classList.remove('mobile-menu'); 
})
```

```css
    :root {
        --primary-color: #007af3;
    }

    body{
        background: #F2F2F2;
        margin: 0 ;
        font-family: 'Poppins'; 
    }

    .navbar {
        background: white;
        padding: 1em;
        
        .logo{
             text-decoration: none;
             font-weight: bold;
             color: black ;
             font-size: 1.2em;

            span {
                 color: var(--primary-color);
            }
        }

        nav{
            display: none;
        }
        .container{
            display: flex;
            place-content: space-between;
        }

        .mobile-menu{
            cursor: pointer;
        }
    }

    a{
        color: #444444;
    }

    ul {
        list-style-type: none;
        margin: 0;
        padding: 0;
    }

    section{
        padding: 5em 2em;
    }

    .hero{
        text-align: center;
    }

    .left-col{

        .subhead{
            text-transform: uppercase;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: gray;
            letter-spacing: .3em;
        }

        h1{
            font-size: 2.5em;
            line-height: 1.3em;
            margin-top: .2em;
        }

        .primary-cta{
            background: var(--primary-color);
            color: white;
            text-decoration: none;
            padding: .6em 1.3em;
            font-size: 1.4em;
            border-radius: 5em;
            font-weight: bold;
            display: inline-block;
        }

        .watch-video-cta{
            display: block;
            margin-top: 1em;
            
            img {
                margin-right: .5em;
            }
        }
    }

    .hero-img{
        width: 70% ;
        margin-top: 3em;
    }

    section.features-section{
        background: #20272e;
        color: white;
    }

    ul.feature-list{
        margin:  0;
        padding-left: .1em;
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(auto-fit , minmax(19rem, 1fr));

        li{
            font-size: 1.1em;
            margin-bottom: 1em;
            margin-left: 2em;
            position: relative;

            &:before{
                content: '';
                left: -2em;
                position: absolute;
                width: 20px;
                height: 20px;
                background-image: url('../2021frontend/images/bullet.svg');
                background-size: contain;
                margin-right: .5em;

            }
        }
        
    }

    .features-section img{
        display: none;
    }


    .testimonials-section{
        background: var(--primary-color);
        color: white;

        li{
            width: #006bd6;
            text-align: center;
            padding: 2em 1em;
            width: 75%;
            margin: 0 auto 5em auto;
            border-radius: 1em;
            
            img{
                width: 5em;
                height: 5em;
                border: 5px solid #006bd6;
                border-radius: 50%;
                margin-top: -4.5em;
            }
        }
    }

    h2{
        font-size: 2em;
    }

    label{
        display: block;
        font-size: 1.2em;
        margin-bottom: .5em;
    }

    input, textarea{
        width: 100%;
        padding: .8em;
        margin-bottom: 1em;
        border-radius: .3em;
        border: 1px solid gray;
        box-sizing: border-box;
    }

    input[type="submit"]{
        background-color: var(--primary-color);
        color: white;
        font-weight: bold;
        font-size: 1.3em;
        border: none;
        margin-bottom: 5em;
        border-radius: 5em;
        display: inline-block;
        padding: .8em 6.7em;
        width: unset;
        cursor: pointer;
    }

    iframe{
        width: 100%;
        height: 300px;
    }

    nav.mobile-menu{
        display: block;
    }

    nav{
        position: fixed;
        z-index: 999;
        width: 66%;
        right: 0;
        top: 0;
        background: #20272e;
        height: 100vh;
        padding: 1em;

        ul.primary-nav{
            margin-top: 5em;
        }

        li{

            a{
                color:white;
                text-decoration: none;
                display: block;
                padding: .5em;
                font-size: 1.3em;
                text-align: right;

                &:hover{
                    font-weight: bold;
                }
            }
        }

    }

    .mobile-mobile-closed {
        float: right;
        margin: .5em;
        cursor: pointer;

    }

    //now here we desinging the pc version of the website

    @media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
        .mobile-menu, .mobile-menu-closed{
            display: none;
        }

        .navbar .container{
            display: grid;
            grid-template-columns: 180px auto;
            justify-content: unset;
            
        }

        .navbar nav{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            background: none;
            position: unset;
            height: auto;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;

            ul{
                display: flex;
            }

            a{
                color: black;
                font-size: 1em;
                padding: .1em 1em; 
            }

            ul.primary-nav{
                margin: 0;
            }

            li.current a{
                font-weight: bold;
            }

            li.go-premium-cta a{
                color: var(--primary-color);
                border: 3px solid var(--primary-color);
                font-weight: bold;
                border-radius: 5em;
                margin-top: -.2em;

                &:hover{
                    background: var(--primary-color);
                    color: white;
                }
            }
        }
    }

    @media only screen and (min-width: 950px) {
        .container{
            width: 950px;
            margin: 0 auto;
        }

        section{
            padding: 10em 4em;
        }
        
        .hero .container{
            display: flex;
            justify-content: space-between;
            text-align: left;

            .left-col{
                margin: 3em 3em 0 5em;

                h1 {
                    font-size: 3em;
                    width: 90%;
                }
            }
        
        }

        .hero-img{
            width: 30%;
            margin-right: 8em;
        }

        .hero-cta{
            display: flex;
        }

        .primary-cta{
            margin-right: 1em;
        }

        ul.features-list{
            display: block;
            margin-left: 5em;

            li{
                font-size: 1.4em;

                &:before{
                    width: 30px;
                    height: 30px;
                }
            }
        }

        .features-section{
            position: relative;
        }

        .features-section img{
            display:block;
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            width: 325px;
            bottom: -6em; 
            height: 250px; 
        }

        .testimonials-section ul{
            display: flex;

            li {
                margin: 0 1em;
                flex-basis: 33.333333%;
            }
        }

        .contact-section{
            position: relative;
            display: flex;
            
        }

        .contact-right{
            position: absolute;
            right: 0;
            top: 0;
            width: 45%;
            height: 100%;

            iframe{
                height: 100%;
            }
        }
    }

    //here we done the styling of 1220px and after
    @media only screen and (min-width: 1220px){
        .features-section{

            &:before{
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                width: 10%;
                height: 20em;
                background: var(--primary-color);
                left: 0;
                top: -4em;
            }

            &:after{
                content: '';
                position: absolute;
                width: 200px;
                height: 18em;
                background: url('../2021frontend/images/dots.svg') no-repeat;
                top: -1em;
                left: auto;
            }
        }
    }
```

```html
        <div class="navbar"> <!-- here class is the name given to the div block so that the css identify it for styling it-->
            <div class="container">
                <a class="logo" href="#">Let's<span>Code</span></a>
                
                <img id="mobile-cta" class="mobile-menu" src="2021frontend/images/menu.svg" alt="Open navigation">

                <nav>
                    <img id="mobile-sta" class="mobile-menu-closed" src="2021frontend/images/exit.svg" alt="Closed navigation">
                    <ul class="primary-nav">
                        <li class="home"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Events</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Registration</a></li>
                    </ul>

                    <ul class="secondary-nav">
                        <li><a href="#">GrowYourMoney</a></li>
                        <li><a href="#">Projects</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </div>
        </div>

        <section  class="hero">
            
            <div class="container">
                <div class="left-col">
                    <p class="subhead">Share with the World &amp; Grow with the World</p>
                    <h1>We are here to make the Future</h1>

                    <div class="hero-cta">
                        <a href="#" class="primary-cta">Click Here</a>
                        <a href="#" class="watch-video-cta">
                            <img src="2021frontend/images/watch.svg" alt="Watch a video">Watch a Video
                        </a>
                    </div>        
                </div>

                <img src="2021frontend/images/illustration.svg" class="hero-img" alt="illustration-images">
            </div>
            
        </section>

        <section class="features-section">
            <div class="container">
                <ul class="feature-list">
                     <li>Full Stack Web Development</li>
                     <li>Full Stack Mobile App Development</li>
                     <li>Cloud tech</li>
                     <li>Devops</li>
                     <li>Web3 Development</li>
                     <li>Stock Market</li>

                </ul>

                <img src="2021frontend/images/holding-phone.jpg" alt="Man holding phone">
            </div>

        </section>

        <section class="testimonials-section">
            <div class="container">
                <ul>
                    <li>
                        <img src="2021frontend/images/person.jpg" alt="person">

                        <blockquote>"has a strong hold in full stack web Development, leader of team antidote in sih prefinal round"</blockquote>
                        <cite>- saksham bansal</cite>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="2021frontend/images/person.jpg" alt="person">

                        <blockquote>"starting my journey as a full stack developer and interested in web3 domain"</blockquote>
                        <cite>- sayan halder</cite>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="2021frontend/images/person.jpg" alt="person">

                        <blockquote>"currently doing frontend development with bootstrap and loves playing football and cricket"</blockquote>
                        <cite>- varun sharma</cite>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="2021frontend/images/person.jpg" alt="person">

                        <blockquote>"currently learning web Development and see myself in future as a android developer "</blockquote>
                        <cite>- parth barara</cite>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="2021frontend/images/person.jpg" alt="person">

                        <blockquote>"iam  the tomper of the class and likes chemistry very much"</blockquote>
                        <cite>- sakshi gupta</cite>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="2021frontend/images/person.jpg" alt="person">

                        <blockquote>"i dont know what i am doing but my boyfriend loves me very much"</blockquote>
                        <cite>- nandini gulati</cite>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="2021frontend/images/person.jpg" alt="person">

                        <blockquote>"same as nandini"</blockquote>
                        <cite>- kushi suri</cite>
                    </li>
                    <li>
                        <img src="2021frontend/images/person.jpg" alt="person">

                        <blockquote>"iam the don of kv, dont even try to fight with me in palam"</blockquote>
                        <cite>- sribash paul</cite>
                    </li>
                </ul>
            </div>

        </section>
        <br>

        <section class="contact-section">
            <div class="contact-left">
                <h2>Contact</h2>

                <form action="">
                    <label for="name">Name</label>
                    <input type="text" id="name" name="name" placeholder="Your Name"> <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="email">Email</label>
                    <input type="email" id="email" name="email" placeholder="@email.com"> <br>
                    <br>
                    <label for="message">Message</label> <br>
                    <textarea name="message" id="message" cols="30" rows="10"></textarea> <br>
                    <br>
                    <input type="submit" class="send-message-cta" value="Send Message">
                </form>
            </div>
            
            <div>
                <div class="contact-right">
                    <iframe src="https://www.google.com/maps/embed?pb=!1m18!1m12!1m3!1d28026.467037845872!2d77.08443149999997!3d28.59052415000001!2m3!1f0!2f0!3f0!3m2!1i1024!2i768!4f13.1!3m3!1m2!1s0x390d1b3f9902dce7%3A0xdf51d27e693abbea!2sPalam%2C%20New%20Delhi%2C%20Delhi!5e0!3m2!1sen!2sin!4v1649777392215!5m2!1sen!2sin" width="600" height="450" style="border:0;" allowfullscreen="" loading="lazy" referrerpolicy="no-referrer-when-downgrade"></iframe>
                </div>
            </div>

            <img src="2021frontend/images/" alt="">
            
        </section>
```

Comment: Please don't SHOUT when asking questions and also take time to format your question properly (probably why you have been downvoted by someone). but your problem will be because you are using fixed heights - eg 100vh - if your content is longer then it will overflow the container.  Try using min-height instead

Comment: i am new to stackoverflow so dont know how to edit questions properly.

Comment: thanks for your suggestion , i take care of it from next time

Comment: can u tell me where to change or add the min height , in the testimonials-section or in the whole css file

Comment: Please trim your code to make it easier to find your problem. Follow these guidelines to create a [minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).

Answer (score 0):

By default `display: flex;` will try and put everything onto one row. Where you have `.testimonials-section ul {` in your 950px breakpoint add `flex-wrap: wrap;`

One thing to note, and I may be mistaken here, is that flex-basis doesn't take margins into consideration, so you will find that your testimonials will be 2 per row instead of 3 because of the horizontal margins you've set. You can fix this by change `flex-basis: 33.3333%` to `flex-basis: calc(33.3333% - 2em);`

Comment: thank u very much now i understand it properly